# How to use angular-gettext in a config phase?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gettext, breadcrumbs, angular-gettext

I'm using [angular-gettext](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext), [angular-breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb) and [angular-ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

I have my app configuration similar to this:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider.state('welcome', {
     url : '/',
     templateUrl: 'index.html',
     ncyBreadcrumb : {
        label : 'Home'
     }
  });

});
```

I would like to be able to translate the label for the breadcrumb (`'Home'`) by `angular-gettext`. In order to this I need to include gettext tools into the `app.config()` function. Something like this would be ideal, however `gettextCatalog` isn't available during the config phase:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, gettextCatalog) {

  $stateProvider.state('welcome', {
     url : '/',
     templateUrl: 'index.html',
     ncyBreadcrumb : {
        label : gettextCatalog.getString('Home')
     }
  });

});
```

Is there any other way to achieve this with these plugins, especially with the `angular-gettext`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [angular-breadcrumb](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/wiki/API-Reference#state-options) docs:

> The property `ncyBreadcrumbLabel` can contains bindings which are evaluated against the scope of the current state controller.

I haven't tested this, but I would think you could use the `gettextCatalog` module in your controller:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'index.html',
  controller: function($scope, gettextCatalog) {
    $scope.label = gettextCatalog.getString('Home');
  },
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
    label: '{{label}}'
  }
})
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution. Another possibility is [this one](https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/issues/65). Even `label: '{{label|translate}}'` works too, however none of these two expressions is detected by `grunt-angular-gettext` extraction so they are useless.